# Change Each List Item Color by X% Using LESS/CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, less

I have a list that could have an unknown number of list items.

I would like to desaturate each list item by, say 5% starting from a base color. Ideally this could be done using LESS, but my mind won't quite wrap around how to do it without declaring rules for each `nth-child`.

As always any and all thoughts appreciated.

```
<ul>
  <li>item1</li> <!-- base color -->
  <li>item2</li> <!-- desaturate 5% -->
  <li>item3</li> <!-- desaturate 10% -->
  <li>item4</li> <!-- desaturate 15% -->
  <li>item5</li> <!-- desaturate 20% -->
</ul>
```

Also, not 100% against using jQuery, would just like not to.

Comment: Like so: https://gist.github.com/edwinwebb/5155504 the rest is pretty simple.. desaturate (index + 1) * 5%

Comment: Awesome, was able to make that work, thank you!

Comment: No problem! Honestly I was a bit lazy to do it, haha, glad you could convert it to your use case :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the link provided by @veksen I was able to get this working. A demo can be found on Codepen here - http://codepen.io/harbingerlabs/pen/obXaMv

Here is the finished code snippet for reference too:

```
/* Define two variables as the loop limits */
@from : 0;
@to : 100;

/* Create a Parametric mixin and add a guard operation */
.loop(@index) when(@index =< @to) {

  /* As the mixin is called CSS is outputted */
  li:nth-child(@{index}) {
    background: spin(@alizarin,3.5 * @index);
  }

  /* Interation call and operation */
  .loop(@index + 1);
}

/* the mixin is called, css outputted and iterations called */
.loop(@from);

ul.colors {
    li {
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .loop(0)
}
```